# Tooltip text sudden added into Arabic text when mouseleave

Tags: javascript, html, replace, tooltip, arabic

I am creating the Tajweed rules that when the I mouseenter, it will replace the selected Tajweed with color and show the tooltip only under the colored Arabic text. But the problem is, when the I mouseleave, the tooltip text is added into the Arabic text.

HTML:

```
<div align="right">
     <span class="enter">ﻣِـنْ أَﺧِﯿﻪِ</span>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$( "span.enter" )
.mouseenter(function() {
var $this=$(this);
 $this.html($this.text().replace(/\u0646\u0652\u0020\u0623\u064E/,'<ruby id="enter" class="tooltip-danger" style="color:red">'+
 unescape("%u0646%u0652%u0020%u0623%u064E")+'</ruby>'));

    $('#enter').tooltip({
       trigger: 'hover',
       placement: 'bottom',
       html: true,
       title: '<span>Read With Bright & Clear</span>'
});
})

.mouseleave(function() {
var $this=$(this);
 $this.html($this.text().replace(/\u0646\u0652\u0020\u0623\u064E/,unescape('%u0646%u0652%u0020%u0623%u064E')));

    $('#enter').tooltip('hide');
});
```

This work like charm, but I have no idea why the tooltip text keep adding to the Arabic text. Thank you.

Here's the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/610bx4k1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmadzhariff/610bx4k1/5/)

**EDIT**

Here example of not accurate tooltip, which I have done previously. It only show tooltip below the div:

[image: The tooltip is only show below the div which I have done previously.]

This example what I want, but when mouseleave, the tooltip text added into Arabic text:

[image: it works, but when mouseleave, tooltip text sudden added into the Arabic text.]

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 0):

the problem lies with the `tooltip` try to add the tooltip to the parent element to avoid this issue :

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/610bx4k1/9/)**

```
$( "span.enter" )
    .mouseenter(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
$this.html($this.text().replace(/\u0646\u0652\u0020\u0623\u064E/,'<ruby id="enter" class="tooltip-danger" style="color:red">'+
    unescape("%u0646%u0652%u0020%u0623%u064E")+'</ruby>'));
    $('#lool').tooltip({  // <-- parent element 
    trigger: 'hover',
    placement: 'bottom',
    html: true,
    title: 'Read With Bright & Clear'
  });
  })

  .mouseleave(function() {
    var $this=$(this);
$this.html($this.text().replace(/\u0646\u0652\u0020\u0623\u064E/,unescape('%u0646%u0652%u0020%u0623%u064E')));
        $('#lool').tooltip('hide'); // <-- parent element
  });
```

also I added this CSS to the parent div to make Div width equal to child contents 
to much the tooltype position whatever the contents size of it's child :

```
#lool {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thank You for your response. I did that previously, but that did not goes on the below of the colored text. It will show tooltip below on the div which means, if there were a longer Arabic text, the placement will not be accurate below the colored Arabic text.